# Haskell: successive modifications of a text

Tags: haskell, text, numbers

I want to know how to make modifications to a text that is full of special characters and codes and replace those codes with strings.

I have the following text:

text=

> "#chomsky/syntactic structures/chomskySynt/: published in 1957. #bloomfield/language/bloomfieldLan/: published in 1933. #chomsky/aspects of a theory of syntax/chomskyAsp/: published in 1965. ... #see/chomskySynt/ is considered the starting point of generative linguistics.... Another hypothesis was introduced in #see/chomskyAsp/."

I want to turn it into=

> "Chomsky 1: Syntactic structures : published in 1957. Bloomfield 1: Language : published in 1933. Chomsky 2: Aspects of a theory of syntax : published in 1965. ... Chomsky 1 is considered the starting point of generative linguistics ... Another hypothesis was introduced in Chomsky 2..."

Explanation of the special characters and codes: the information on a book starts with # followed by the name of the author (chomsky for example) followed by / then title of the book / then the special code for the book (chomskyAsp)  then /

The citation of a book starts with #see followed by / then the special code of the book (ex. chomskySyn) /

The modifications are:

1. To count how many times an author is cited and concatenate the number to the name: Chomsky 1, for example.
2. Author name will start with a capital letter
3. Remove the special code : chomskySynt which serves only as an identification code.
4. Replace the reference : #see/chomskyAsp   with the Chomsky 2. That is replace the reference with the actual author and number.

Here is my code:

```
  RemoveSlash = myReplace "/"" " text

  removeDash = map lines $ (filter(any isLetter) . groupBy ( (==) `on`       (=='#'))) $ removeSlash

  flattenList= concat removeDash 

   splitIntoWords = map words flattenList
```

And here is the myReplace function:

```
     myReplace _ _ [] = []
     myReplace a b s@(x:xs)= if isPrefixOf a s
              then b++myReplace a b (drop(length a)s)
              else x: myReplace a b xs
```

Here is the result so far:

> [["chomsky syntactic structures chomskySynt  published in 1957. "],    ["bloomfield language bloomfieldLan  published in 1933.  "],["chomsky aspects of a theory of syntax chomskyAsp  published in 1965. ... "],["see chomskySynt  is considered the starting point of generative linguistics.... Another hypothesis was introduced in "],["see chomskyAsp"]]

The reason I flattened the list and split it into words is now if I do:

```
      map head splitIntoWords
```

I get ["chomsky","bloomfield","chomsky","see","see"]

I am stuck at this stage. How do I count how many times an author is cited and concatenate the number to the name. I thought of using the zip function:

```
    zipChomsky =zip [1, 2][x | x <- diviser,(head x) == "chomsky"]
```

This gives:

> [(1["chomsky","syntactic","structures","chomskySynt","published","in","1957."]),(2,["chomsky","aspects","of","a","theory","of","syntax","chomskyAsp","published","in","1965.","..."])]

But the result is very different from:  Chomsky 1: ...

Comment: Perhaps it is time to define a real data structure representing your document, a parser that turns flat text into that structure, and some operations on that structure!

Comment: @Daniel Wagner Yes I tried to create a type: data Author = Author String String String deriving(Show) . And the functions: name(Author name _ _ )= name, title(Author _ title _)= title, and finally code(Author _ _ code)= code. But how do I inject this data into the text?

Comment: That looks like a decent type for authors, but doesn't cover documents (which can include both plain text and authors) very well yet. No problem: add more data types!

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: but suppose I want to limit myself to the authors. How do I extract the information into the data type and then put it back into the text again. Sorry if I sound redundant, I am a noob in Haskell and I don't understand how to inject the info in a data structure back to a text. Thanks

Comment: `renderAuthor (Author first last) = first ++ " " ++ last`.  There are better ways to "pretty print" ASTs into text but simple string concatenation as shown here can get your fairly far.

Comment: Just making sure - you know that there already exist systems like bibtex that already do a tremendous job at what you want to achieve.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Thanks for pointing out this library. but my request is more pedagogical, I am learning haskell, and I wanted a direction/ hint on how to create a data structure to map the text structure. So I started with Author but I guess I could just extend it to include plain text that does not refer to an author, as suggested by Daniel Wagner. And I am not looking for a ready-made solution either, because this is an assignment and I want to know how to solve it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I didn't mean to make the answer this long, but the problem turned out a non-trivial task, and I'm not quite sure how much detail I should put in the answer. In case you understand all the tools I'm using, the full code is just at the end of this answer.

---

In your case, you'll need:

- an approach to parse your input document
- a suitable data structure to store the input information
- displaying the data as output format

For the parsing part, perhaps Regex is enough (maybe), but I guess the [Parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) library is a better choice. For detailed usage of Parsec please refer to the link, and I'll only try to show how to use it in your case:

First, `import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec`.

A document is a `list` of

- a literal string
- a `definition`, with format `#<Author>/<Title>/<Code>/`, as in "#chomsky/syntactic structures/chomskySynt/"
- a `citation`, with format `#see/<Code>/`, as in "#see/chomskyAsp/"

Hence we define

```
data Index = Index {
    getAuthor      :: String,
    getTitle       :: String,
    getSpecialCode :: String,
    getAuthorCount :: Int
        -- For counting author later.
} deriving (Show)

data Content = Def Index
             | Cite String Index
             -- We'll fill in Index later.
             | Literal String
    deriving (Show)
```

and our input document will just be turned into `[Content]`.

Correspondingly, we'll use the following function (actually, parser) to parse the input:

```
document = many (try def <|> try cite <|> literal)

literal = Literal <$> many1 (noneOf "#")

def = do
    char '#'
    author <- many1 $ noneOf "/"
    char '/'
    title <- many1 $ noneOf "/"
    char '/'
    code <- many1 $ noneOf "/"
    char '/'
    return $ Def author title code

cite = do
    try $ string "#see/"
    code <- many1 $ noneOf "/"
    char '/'
    return $ Cite code nullIndex
```

A short explanation:

1. A `document` is `many` (`def` or `cite` or `literal`), with operator `<|>` combining parsers.
2. A `literal` is a string, stopping at `'#'`, with at least 1 char (using `many1`); a parser inside `many` should not accept empty input, think of why!
3. A `def` is `#<Author>/<Title>/<Code>/`, and we can write in do-notation since `Parser` is a monad.
4. A `cite` goes similarly.
5. A `def`, `cite`, or `string "#see/"` parse multiple characters, hence is possible to fail when they *have consumed* some chars; therefore, we use the combinator `try`.
6. By the way, `nullIndex` is just a placeholder before we actually fill this record:

   ```
   nullIndex :: Index
   nullIndex = Index "" "" "" 0
   ```

---

Now we only need a function with signiture `[Content] -> String`.

We can start with captializing the author name:

```
capitalizeAuthor :: Content -> Content
capitalizeAuthor (Def x) = Def (x {getAuthor = author'}) where
    author' = toUpper (head author) : tail author
    author  = getAuthor x
capitalizeAuthor y = y
```

The other tasks are not *local*, since the relation between `Content`s should be observed, hence we will use a `foldl` across the list.

Define

```
import           Data.Map.Strict               ((!))
import qualified Data.Map.Strict               as M

type CodeDict = M.Map String Index
    -- Map Code Index
type AuthorDict = M.Map String Int
    -- Map Author Count
type Fold = (CodeDict, AuthorDict, [Content])

emptyFold :: Fold
emptyFold = (M.empty, M.empty, [])
```

The `Fold` type will store the state when we modify along the original `[Content]`.

(I realize that the code will be much clearer if I use the `State` monad, but I'm not sure if I need to explain it then ...)

In addition, a folding function for `foldl`

```
accum :: Fold -> Content -> Fold
accum (c,a,ls) (Def x) = (c',a',Def x':ls) where
    a' = M.insertWith (+) author 1 a
    c' = M.insert code x' c
    x' = x {getAuthorCount = count}
    count = maybe 1 (+1) $ a !? author
    author = getAuthor x
    code = getSpecialCode x
accum (c,a,ls) (Cite code _) = (c,a,Cite code (c ! code) : ls)
accum (c,a,ls) y = (c,a,y:ls)
```

After `foldr`, the resulted list will contain the contents with

- `getAuthorCount` correctly filled
- `Cite`s transferred into `Def`s, since they have the same outputting format.
- The resulted list is reversed, so you'll need `Data.List.reverse`.

Finally, you can define your own version of `Show` for `Content`. For example,

```
instance Show Index where
    show x = getAuthor x ++ " "
          ++ show (getAuthorCount x) ++ ": "
          ++ getTitle x ++ " "

instance Show Content where
    show (Def idx)     = show idx
    show (Cite x idx)  = getAuthor idx ++ " "
                      ++ show (getAuthorCount idx)
    show (Literal x)   = x
```

as I figured out from your output sample.

---

The full length code:

```
import           Data.Char
import           Data.List                     (reverse)
import           Data.Map.Strict               ((!),(!?))
import qualified Data.Map.Strict               as M
import           Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Index = Index {
    getAuthor      :: String,
    getTitle       :: String,
    getSpecialCode :: String,
    getAuthorCount :: Int
        -- For counting author later.
}

nullIndex :: Index
nullIndex = Index "" "" "" 0

instance Show Index where
    show x = getAuthor x ++ " "
          ++ show (getAuthorCount x) ++ ": "
          ++ getTitle x ++ " "

data Content = Def Index
             | Cite String Index
             | Literal String

instance Show Content where
    show (Def idx)     = show idx
    show (Cite x idx)  = getAuthor idx ++ " "
                      ++ show (getAuthorCount idx)
    show (Literal x)   = x

document = many (try cite <|> try def <|> literal)

literal = Literal <$> many1 (noneOf "#")

def = do
    char '#'
    author <- many1 $ noneOf "/"
    char '/'
    title <- many1 $ noneOf "/"
    char '/'
    code <- many1 $ noneOf "/"
    char '/'
    return $ Def $ Index author title code 0

cite = do
    try $ string "#see/"
    code <- many1 $ noneOf "/"
    char '/'
    return $ Cite code nullIndex

capitalizeAuthor :: Content -> Content
capitalizeAuthor (Def x) = Def (x {getAuthor = author'}) where
    author' = toUpper (head author) : tail author
    author  = getAuthor x
capitalizeAuthor y = y

type CodeDict = M.Map String Index
    -- Map Code Index
type AuthorDict = M.Map String Int
    -- Map Author Count
type Fold = (CodeDict, AuthorDict, [Content])

emptyFold :: Fold
emptyFold = (M.empty, M.empty, [])

accum :: Fold -> Content -> Fold
accum (c,a,ls) (Def x) = (c',a',Def x':ls) where
    a' = M.insertWith (+) author 1 a
    c' = M.insert code x' c
    x' = x {getAuthorCount = count}
    count = maybe 1 (+1) $ a !? author
    author = getAuthor x
    code = getSpecialCode x
accum (c,a,ls) (Cite code _) = (c,a,Cite code (c ! code) : ls)
accum (c,a,ls) y = (c,a,y:ls)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    line <- getLine
    let parsed = parse document "" line
    case parsed of
      Left x -> print x
      Right cs -> do
        let cs1 = map capitalizeAuthor cs
        let (_,_,cs2) = foldl accum emptyFold cs1
        let output = concatMap show $ reverse cs2
        putStrLn output
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer, especially for the data structure and how to use it on the text.!!!